# Payara Micro - 404 after deployment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, payara, payara-micro

I wanted to try this cool micro app server - Payara Micro, but Im somehow unable to deploy the simplest example possible. 
I've created a blank web-app maven project from netbeans, using JavaEE7 with no dependencies. Tried to compile it (nothing much to compile), and ran it successfully with Glassfish 4.1.1 - Hello World welcome page appears, and everything is OK.

Did a clean&build, and tried to deploy resulting WARfile to payara.
(java -jar payara-micro.jar --deploy mywarfile.war)
Startup was quick, just noticed two messages in output - > "No META-INF/deploy" directory and "Deployed 1 archives".
Tried to open the index page, but oops -> error 404 (as seen below).

[image]

The project is really simple, I may be doing something wrong when deploying. Maybe some errors in project structure ? 
Hereby I present the primitive project structure used :

[image]

Thank you very much for any valuable solution/feedback. I think I'm just overlooking some minor, stupid thing.

Edit: pomfile attached. Tried to run it with both dependencies, with EE or payara only, but no change :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.myproject.sigag</groupId>
<artifactId>sigag</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>sigag</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>payara-micro</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.152.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you add your `pom.xml`? I can see you've got the Java EE 7 web API as a dependency, but you're better off using Payara Micro as a `provided` scope dependency. Payara Micro has Web profile APIs, plus a couple of others, like JCache, so that should help.

Comment: http://blog.payara.fish/using-payara-embedded-and-payara-micro-with-maven

Comment: Edit: I've added my pom.xml, tried your solution, but with  no success so far :(

Comment: Can you update your question with the URL you tried in the browser, and the output in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to see in the logs the context root of your application (couple of lines before the line `Payara Micro  4.1.1.163 #badassmicrofish (build 215) ready in 10436 (ms)`).

Something like this:

```
Loading application [sigag] at [/sigag]
```

Then your application should be available at http://localhost:8080/sigag/

Comment: Thanks alot. Why is so hard to find?

Answer (score 1):

thank you very much, for your effort.
After all, it was really stupid mistake and I'm kinda sorry I wasted your time.

The answer is simple - based on filename of the war - the deploy URL is created.
So basically - since I had a full "Mavenous" file name : Sigag-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war, the correct URL of deployed app was `localhost:8080/Sigag-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/`

Thanks again for your answers.

Comment: Great! Please mark one of the answers as the correct answer, so that people know it was resolved. You may mark also your own answer as correct.